# .NET HttpClient with request header "Range" is not working

Tags: c#, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient

With this `curl` command:

```sh
> curl --range 0-999 -I https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/497.09/497.09-desktop-win10-win11-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe
```

The response correctly returns as:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Content-Range: bytes 0-999/870849168
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Sun, 12 Dec 2021 17:38:31 GMT
Etag: "1774295931"
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Dec 2021 12:42:07 GMT
Content-Length: 1000
```

When using the .NET `HttpClient`, it appears to fail with a range request header:

```cs
var url = "https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/497.09/497.09-desktop-win10-win11-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe";

var req = new HttpRequestMessage();
req.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
req.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
// req.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, 999);  // not working
req.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=0-999");  // not working
WriteLine(req.ToString() );

var client2 = new HttpClient();
var respTask2 = client2.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var resp2 = respTask2.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
WriteLine(resp.ToString() );
```

The `HttpClient` response returns as:

```
Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/497.09/497.09-desktop-win10-win11-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  Range: bytes=0-999
}
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Date: Sun, 12 Dec 2021 17:44:07 GMT
  ETag: "1774295931"
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Dec 2021 12:42:07 GMT
  Content-Length: 870849168
}
```

How do you use the `Range` header with `HttpClient` request? I wonder if this is a bug or what?

Reference: [HttpRequestHeaders.Range Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.range)

Comment: Does `req.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes");` work better?

Comment: @LajosArpad How will I specify the range numbers then?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and once fixed, doesn't produce the response you posted. It actually returns `Content-Length: 1000`. It look like you've mixed up multiple requests and responses and print the wrong response. Don't rush to assume something used by every .NET Core developer is broken. Create a new empty project and add the *minimal* code necessary to reproduce the bug. If you can't, the problem is in the rest of your code

Comment: PS: Don't use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Use `async/await` instead. You can use `async Task Main(string[] args)` in your Main method, so there's seldom any reason to block

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos When a console app's `Main` becomes `async`, it just return to console prompt when the line of `await` reached. I just don't like that behaviour because it seems out of my control, so here comes the good old `GetAwaiter`.

Comment: That's not what happens at all. The application behaves exactly the same, except now you can use `await` and avoid the clutter that hid what your code was actually doing. Before `async Task Main` people used to create a separate `MainAsync` and call it with `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` rather than litter their code with `.Wait()` and `.Result`

Comment: You also avoid the deadlocks that can be caused when multiple async operations block each other

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Apparently it's my bad. I'm kinda too lazy to deploy MainAsync for a quick experiment. However wait a minute, how come turn all `async` into `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` induce deadlocks? Ain't they just synchronous calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RangeHeaderValue` appears to be working as expected under net5.0:

```cs
var url = "https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/497.09/497.09-desktop-win10-win11-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe";
var client = new HttpClient();
var req = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri( url ) };
req.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue( 0, 999 );

var resp = await client.SendAsync( req );

Console.WriteLine( $"\r\nResponse:\r\n{resp}" );
```

With the Response Output:

```json
StatusCode: 206, ReasonPhrase: 'Partial Content', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Age: 18147
  Cache-Control: max-age=86400
  Date: Sun, 12 Dec 2021 18:25:42 GMT
  ETag: "1774295931"
  Server: ECAcc
  Server: (daa/7CFD)
  X-Cache: HIT
  x-vdms-version: 117
  Content-Range: bytes 0-999/870849168
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Expires: Mon, 13 Dec 2021 18:25:42 GMT
  Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Dec 2021 12:42:07 GMT
  Content-Length: 1000
}
```

Upon further inspection of your posted code:

```cs
var resp2 = respTask2.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
WriteLine(resp.ToString() );
```

Notice the `WriteLine` is for `resp.ToString()`, but should be using `resp2.ToString()`. So, it appears you're actually printing out some other response.